# How much blood flows to female breasts?

Tags: human-biology, blood-circulation

How much of the entire blood in the body blood flows to the breast (while resting). If you know the percentage or absolute values , as well as the total cardiac output, I would appreciate it answers or referrals to publications or tables. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this paper](https://www.academicradiology.org/article/S1076-6332(13)00497-2/pdf) is relevant, but I don't have access to it.

Comment: [This paper](http://cancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/52/6/1592.full-text.pdf) has an answer for a normal tissue in a patient with cancer. It is known that also blood flow of normal tissue increases near the presence of a cancerous tumor.

Comment: By resting do you mean supine or upright?

Comment: Resting = sitting on a chair.